# How to find nearest bigger 2**n value to a value?

Tags: python

My goal is to get nearest bigger number than an input integer that is two to the n.

For example, what should `nearestbigger` be?

```
integerinput = [2016, 300, 9001]
for x in integerinput:
    print(nearestbigger(x))
```

Expected Output

```
2048
512
16384
```

Comment: I've reopened this question because OP is seeking a python soluiton, whereas the so-called duplicate is cross-language, and in fact there is now python solution there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def nearesbigger(n):
    if n <= 0:
        return 1
    return 2 ** (n-1).bit_length()
```